# How can I write one-to-one and onto in predicate logic?

Tags: predicate-logic

How can I write one-to-one and onto in predicate logic?

$\forall a \forall b(a\in X  \land b\in Y, a \implies b)$

This seems very wrong, but I don't know any other way to do it.

Comment: The first thing to figure out is _what_ you want to say is one-to-one and onto.  _E.g._ you might write: if $f$ is a function then "$f$ is one-to-one and onto" may be expressed in predicate logic as "...$f$...."

Comment: And yes, what you wrote is indeed extremely wrong :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need a name for the function that you want to describe as a bijection from $X$ to $Y$; I’ll call it $f$.

- $f$ is a relation from $X$ to $Y$: $$\forall z\Big(z\in f\to\exists x\exists y\big(x\in X\land y\in Y\land z=\langle x,y\rangle\big)\Big)$$
- $f$ is a function with domain $X$: $$\forall x\left(x\in X\to\exists y\big(y\in Y\land \langle x,y\rangle\in f\land\forall z\big((z\in Y\land\langle x,z\rangle\in f)\to z=y\big)\Big)\right)$$
- $f$ is a surjection: $$\forall y\Big(y\in Y\to\exists x\big(x\in X\land\langle x,y\rangle\in f\big)\Big)$$
- $f$ is an injection: $$\forall x\forall y\forall z\Big(\big(x\in X\land z\in X\land\langle x,z\rangle\in f\land\langle y,z\rangle\in f\big)\to x=z\Big)$$

The conjunction of these three expressions says that $f$ is a bijection from $X$ onto $Y$.

I find them easier to read in the following form:

$$\begin{align*}
&\forall z\in f\,\exists x\in X\,\exists y\in Y\big(z=\langle x,y\rangle\big)\\\\
&\forall x\in X\,\exists y\in Y\Big(\langle x,y\rangle\in f\land\forall z\in Y(\langle x,z\rangle\in f\to z=y\Big)\\\\
&\forall y\in Y\,\exists x\in X\big(\langle x,y\rangle\in f\big)\\\\
&\forall x,y\in X\,\forall z\in Y\Big(\big(\langle x,y\rangle\in f\land\langle y,z\rangle\in f\big)\to x=z\Big)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I don't think the first clause incorporates $X$ and $Y$ in the right way. It says that $f \cap (X \times Y)$ is a function $X \to Y$, but doesn't say that $f \subset X \times Y$.

Comment: @Trevor: Yep; easiest solution is to split it as I’ve just done. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  However, it still allows $f$ to contain elements that aren't ordered pairs. Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: @Trevor: Gah. You’re right. That’s what I get for coming back right after taking a nap. Should be okay now, though.